# Does a pump like this exist?

Tags: vacuum

I have a need for a pump that can suck a vapor from a 0.1 atm environment, and flow into a 1 atm environment. I know that there are electrical pumps that can do this. But are there any pumps like this that can be operated manually? (powered by hand or body weight)

Comment: Yes. What flow rate do you need? What size constraints do you have? This is certainly possible but we can't recommend anything specific without way more information.

Answer (score 2):

I've owned a hand-held pistol-type vacuum pump, useful for testing distributor advance (yeah, long time ago). A quick search shows the inexpensive versions are capable of 0.6-0.7 atm, not quite what you seek.

Additional searching (reading from the links) allowed me to discover a similar design, listed as capable of 0.1 atm. If you require to remove vapor from this environment, you'd need a pump to go slightly lower in order to have a proper differential.

I'm not sure of your presentation. How did the environment reach 0.1 atm, or are you wishing to take a 1 atm chamber down to 0.1 atm? If the latter, and the volume is not too great, the one I've found may work for you.

At US$259, it should be a better performer than the thirty or forty dollar versions.
[hand vacuum pump from PowerProbe](https://www.powerprobe.com/web-store-1/lrhv90-vacuumpressure-kit?rq=vacuum%20pump)

[image: PowerProbe vacuum pump]

Using the terms "manual vacuum pump" provided these results. No manipulation of terms provided for a foot operated vacuum pump, although references were found for converting a bicycle floor pump to vacuum. It's unlikely that such a pump would reach 0.1 atm, however.